# PHPBB adding custom page in a new directory

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

My version of PHPBB is installed `/board` of my site

I am trying to make a custom page inside a new directory called `store` the file is called `decals.php`

**decals.php**

```
<?php
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();

page_header('Store - Decals');

$template->set_filenames(array(
    'body' => 'store_decals_body.html',
));

make_jumpbox(append_sid("{$phpbb_root_path}viewforum.$phpEx"));
page_footer();

?>
```

the `store_decals_body.html` is uploaded to my `styles` directory and i cant seem to get `mysite.com/board/store/decals.php` to work. It always put me to `mysite.com/board`

Have I overlooked something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the PHP file in a subdirectory, change the root path accordingly:

```
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : '../';
```